# Error with password that begins with EQUALS sign

Tags: xml, oauth-2.0, apigee

I am currently working on Apigee configuration for oauth call and I am using Service Callout. In the I first Get value from KVM:
`<Get assignTo="private.kvm-password"><Key><Parameter>password</Parameter></Key>`

Then I have Service Callout with like this:
`<Payload>grant_type=password&amp;username={private.kvm-username}&amp;password={private.kvm-password}</Payload>`

Now the issue is that we currently use password that begins with EQUALS sign, so the when I check trace there is this: password==.... which fails the auth probably because it thinks operand changed from IS to EQUALS. I tried changing password and that works so this is definitely the issue, however I wanted to know if  it's possible to prevent this issue instead of changing password. I tried HTMLEncode and URLEncode but it didn't change. Also I tired specifying content type to x-www-form-urlencoded but still no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I was able to test this scenario using mocked up data, and I see the values being passed/received properly. Where exactly in trace are you seeing the operand change?

Comment: Service Callout step in Apigee trace. I tried removing the EQUALS sign but after that the password has & sign which also fails. Simple password like "test" works though, so it's definitely issue with password. Error code is steps.servicecallout.ExecutionFailed

Comment: Can you try using <FormParams> tags instead of <Payload>? Also, is your oauth endpoint also an Apigee endpoint?